# Check if material2 sidenav is open

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

Is there a way to check if the `sidenav` element is open? According the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav) documentation, there is a `isOpen?` parameter, but in my case it throws an exception: `EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:2:2 caused by: this.sidenav.isOpen is not a function`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  template: `
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
      Sidenav
  </md-sidenav>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css'],
  host: {
      '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
  }
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sidenav: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick() {
     if (this.sidenav.isOpen()) {
         this.sidenav.close();
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? any output?

Comment: @galvan, sorry. I've updated the post with exception I get.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use `ViewChild` to get control over `sidenav`

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: any;
opened: any = false;
onClick() {
   console.log(this.sidenav.opened);
}
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LmWUqJyHJyP2J6Gv05MZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand the documentation, isOpen? is an optional parameter of the toggle function.

You can check it's property instead. This works for me:

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;
onClick() {
  console.log(`isOpen: ${this.sidenav.opened}`);
}
```